# Md-menu closes after clicking md-tab inside

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular2-template, angular2-md-tabs

I built an `md-menu`  with an `md-tab-group` inside, using Angular Material 2. On each `md-tab` I display a different list. The behavior I'm expecting to see is that the user to be able to switch between tabs and the `md-menu` to stay opened.

The thing is that the `md-menu` closing on every click on one of the tabs.

```
 <img src="/assets/images/ic-notifications.png" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu"/> 

 <md-menu #appMenu="mdMenu"  [overlapTrigger]="false" yPosition="below" xPosition="before" class="notifications-dropdown">
  <md-tab-group >
   <md-tab label="My profile" id="personal">          
     <div class="row notification-row" *ngFor = "let notification of profile_notifications">
        ...
      </div>
   </md-tab>
   <md-tab label="Favorites " id="favorite-tab" >  
  ...
      </md-tab>
   </md-tab-group>
</md-menu>
```

How can I prevent the `md-menu` from closing?

Comment: `<md-tab label="My profile" id="personal">` this is not closed

Comment: @onetwo12 - One can only assume that, since not all code is shown here.

Comment: @Emanuela colta - Can you put your code into a plunker? You have one with imported material [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/o077B6uEiiIgkC0S06dd?p=info)

Comment: The first tab is by default opened. As long as I am not clicking anywhere (to the opened tab or the other one), of course the md-menu stays opened. But the issue occurs when I click on one of the tabs.  @BogdanC , yes, right now I am putting the code in plunker. But I need to clean it before because not all of the data there is relevant. https://plnkr.co/edit/o077B6uEiiIgkC0S06dd?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/F8lGpNVKhsx9q5TPT8LE?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the mouse click propagation. You can do it like this:

```
<md-menu #appMenu="mdMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" yPosition="below" xPosition="before" class="notifications-dropdown">
    <md-tab-group (click)="stopClickPropagate($event)">
        <md-tab label="My profile" id="personal"></md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Favorites " id="favorite-tab"></md-tab>
    </md-tab-group>
</md-menu>
```

and in your component.ts file:

```
stopClickPropagate(event: any){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Link to [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wtr0Uqsui81MBw4AHTju?p=preview).