# i am using material 2 in angular 4 is there any way to to keep the the <mat-menu> open up until don't click on button to close until

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using material 2 in angular 4 is there any way to keep the 
the `<mat-menu>` open up until I don't click on the create button to close

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <span class="new-Language padding-left-8 questionnary-tr">New Language</span>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <img class="flag" [src]="selectedFlag" />
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedcountry" (change)="checkflag(selectedcountry)">
            <mat-option  *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.country">
            {{language.country}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button class="btnBackground">CREATE</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: you need to do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45864743/1791913

Comment: thanks @Faisal  it worked  for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keep mat-menu open angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51104075/keep-mat-menu-open-angular)