# keep mat-menu open angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use checkbox options in a menu, but I need to keep the menu open until the user is finished selecting options. I am using the latest version of Angular. Thank you in advance!

[image]

I have combined the nested mat-menu from [here](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples) with checkboxes:

**What I have tried, but the menu closes after a checkbox is selected:**

```
<mat-menu #worldtest="matMenu" md-prevent-menu-close="md-prevent-menu-close">
     <section><mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checked">Checked</mat-checkbox></section>
     <section><mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="indeterminate">Indeterminate</mat-checkbox></section>
</mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you use a checkbox (or any interactive element that responds to clicks) on a mat-menu, and you don't want the menu to close when you click it, you need to prevent the menu from receiving the click event by stopping it with `MouseEvent.stopPropagation()`. Try something like this:

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Check Me</mat-checkbox>
```

The `md-prevent-menu-close` feature is from the old Angular Material for AngularJS - the 'latest version' of Angular Material (v6) doesn't have that feature. Angular Material (v1.x for AngularJS) and Angular Material2 (v2/5/6 for Angular) are not interchangeable.

Comment: doesn't work (anymore?) for me unfortunately. i am using Angular 11.

Comment: @SuperMensch - works just fine in Angular 11 and 12 for me